# How to shade color in bar legend

Tags: color, legending

I have customized the bar legend I need for my contourPlot but I need a sort of shade between each two of them, like "Hue" function.

```
BarLegend[{{Black, Gray, White, Yellow, Orange, Red, 
RGB 255 255 0}, {-1, 1}}, {-1, -(2/3), -(1/3), 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
BarLegend[
  {{Black, Gray, White, Yellow, Orange, Red}, {-1, 1}}, 
  Subdivide[-1., 1., 2000],
  LegendMarkerSize -> 250]
```

[image: legend]